# Unable to run worklight application without internet connection

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a big problem with running worklight application without enabled wifi or mobile data connections. The application starts and then quit, i need to get to the home screen and then implement some logic.
**wlCommonInit** is never called in that case. I debugged application and saw that something is sending message "onMessage(exit,null)" and then calls **onDestroy()**

**Steps to reproduce:
- Turn off wifi and mobile data and start the application**

Used environments:
 - Worklight 6.2
 - Android

Comment: You're not explaining what you're doing in your application: if it's attempting to connect to the server on startup or not, and if yes - then how. In short - provide something that can be debugged.

Comment: In native i do something like this in onCreate() :
`WL.createInstance(this);
  WL.getInstance().showSplashScreen(this);
  WL.getInstance().initializeWebFramework(getApplicationContext(), this);
if (result.getStatusCode() == WLInitWebFrameworkResult.SUCCESS) {
   super.loadUrl(WL.getInstance().getMainHtmlFilePath());
   // Custom webView
   this.appView.setWebViewClient(makeWebViewClient(appView));
  }
`

In js i try to connect like this:
`WL.Client.connect({ onSuccess: wlInitSuccess, onFailure: wlInitFailure});`


after loadUrl its called the application goes to onDestroy

Comment: Again, it would be easier to debug if you could provide a sample application (doesn't have to be yours specifically) that this problem can be reproduced with. Also mention *reproduction steps* with it. -- *please don't use the comments for this, you have an edit button for the question*

Comment: Please provide your js code.

Comment: @Mo.Ashfaq what exactly do you need from js code

Comment: @Balflear wlInitSuccess and wlInitFailure function code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Worklight 6.2.0.01 I've created a new Hybrid application with the Android environment.

This application performs the below. The application was installed in an Android Nexus 5 device running Android OS 5. The device was set to Airplane mode (no WiFi, no 3G). Upon launching the application the `onFailure` function was invoked, as expected. No crash.

Provide your implementation so that it could be debugged.

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    WL.Client.connect({onSuccess: success, onFailure: failure});    
}

function success() {
    alert ("success");
}

function failure() {
    alert ("failure");
}
```

Comment: I've created too a new project and start it in **airplane mode** and the **onFailure** event is fired exactly as you said, but in mine app is not.    Is it possible the **adapters** to be responsible for that behavior, because i didn't see many differences with the newly created app and mine...

Comment: Adapters should not cause a crash either. We've asked you several times now - provide a project that crashes for you.

Comment: I compared the newly created app and mine and i saw what is the reason for this behavior. It was mine code...
10x